# Nest XML Elements - XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to sandwich an element inside of another element. Is it possible to serialize XML like this?

http://pastebin.com/7qDE7Ses

Here is my class

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SalesOrderMod")]
public partial class SalesOrderMod
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public string TxnID { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
    public string EditSequence { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)]
    public string ShipDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]
    public ListRef ShipMethodRef = new ListRef();

    public bool ShouldSerializeShipMethodRef()
    {
        return !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ShipMethodRef.FullName));
    }

    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 5)]
    public string Other { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 6, ElementName = "SalesOrderLineMod")]
    public List<LineMod> SalesOrderLineMod = new List<LineMod>();

    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 7, ElementName = "SalesOrderLineGroupMod")]
    public List<LineMod> SalesOrderLineGroupMod = new List<LineMod>();
}
```

Comment: Is the class corresponding to `SalesOrderLineGroupRet` a subtype of `SalesOrderLineRet`?

Comment: Provide a minimal example of input and desired output and include that in your posting. The whole file is too much. What elements should be flattened? What happens to the other elements? And which should be ignored or transformed?

Comment: Yes.  Use [XmlElement("SalesOrderLineRet")] List<object> salesOrderLineRet {get;set;}.  Make object string, int, class, ...

Comment: OK, I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You originally indicated you would like to serialize a series of elements inside an XML document like so:

> ```
> <SalesOrderLineRet>
> </SalesOrderLineRet>
> <SalesOrderLineGroupRet>
> </SalesOrderLineGroupRet>
> <SalesOrderLineRet>
> </SalesOrderLineRet>
> ```

You can if the types that correspond to `SalesOrderLineRet` and `SalesOrderLineGroupRet` have some common base type `T`, and they are stored in a `List<T>`.  For instance, the following class definitions:

```
public abstract class SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class SalesOrderLineRet : SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class SalesOrderLineGroupRet : SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class RootObject
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(SalesOrderLineRetBase))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(SalesOrderLineRet))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(SalesOrderLineGroupRet))]
    public List<SalesOrderLineRetBase> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Will, when serialized, produce the following XML:

> ```
> <RootObject>
>     <SalesOrderLineRet />
>     <SalesOrderLineGroupRet />
> </RootObject>
> ```

Using [`[XmlElement(typeof(T))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) tells `XmlSerializer` that the list should be serialized without an outer container element, and that items of type `T` can be expected to be found in the list.  You *must* apply `[XmlElement(typeof(T))]` once for each type `T` that will be stored in the list.

(You can use `List<object>` if the types in the list have no other more derived base type, however I don't recommend that.  I would instead recommending grouping the possible types of list entry under a specific base type.)

If you would prefer your list to be serialized with an outer container element, you can use [`[XmlArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) and [`[XmlArrayItem(typeof(T))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx):

```
public abstract class SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class SalesOrderLineRet : SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class SalesOrderLineGroupRet : SalesOrderLineRetBase
{
}

public class RootObject
{
    [XmlArray("SalesOrders")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(SalesOrderLineRetBase))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(SalesOrderLineRet))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(SalesOrderLineGroupRet))]
    public List<SalesOrderLineRetBase> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Which produces the following XML:

> ```
> <RootObject>
>     <SalesOrders>
>         <SalesOrderLineRet />
>         <SalesOrderLineGroupRet />
>     </SalesOrders>
> </RootObject>
> ```

You must apply `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(T))]` for each type `T` that will be stored in the list.

(Since you don't include the relevant classes and XML in your question, I'm not sure which one you might want.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have a root object. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: @JosephAnderson - I made up a hypothetical root object because your question doesn't show a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  If you can make up such an example, I can update the answer.  However, a valid XML document must have a [single root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).